# How can I add a single domain to be redirected to an existing OpenVPN configuration?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn

I am a novice when it comes to VPN configuration, with almost no experience configuring or tuning VPN settings.  I have an existing working `.ovpn` file configuring a VPN connection within my organization's network.

I have a resource outside the organization's domain that needs accessed through the VPN.  I know that I can add `redirect-gateway def1` to my `.ovpn` file redirect all traffic through the VPN.  A colleague has this configuration working on their machine.

[Reference manual for OpenVPN 2.4](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/#tunnel-options):

> **--redirect-gateway flags...**
> Automatically execute routing commands to cause all outgoing IP traffic to be redirected over the VPN. This is a client-side option. This option performs three steps:
> Create a static route for the **--remote** address which forwards to the pre-existing default gateway. This is done so that the third step will not create a routing loop.
> Delete the default gateway route.
> Set the new default gateway to be the VPN endpoint address (derived either from **--route-gateway** or the second parameter to **--ifconfig** when **--dev tun** is specified).
>
> […]
>
> Option flags:
>
> […]
>
> **def1** -- Use this flag to override the default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.

I don't love this option, as I would prefer to only have necessary traffic redirected over the VPN, not all outgoing IP traffic.

Is there a way to add only the additional domain to my `.ovpn` configuration file?

### Example

To make it concrete, let's say I have the following working `.ovpn` file:

```
remote vpn.example.com 1194
proto udp
ns-cert-type server

client
dev tun
resolv-retry infinite
keepalive 10 120
nobind
comp-lzo
mssfix 1331
verb 3

## Certs etc. follow (omitted from example for brevity)
```

Let's say that I also want all traffic coming from the `otherdomain.invalid` to be redirected through the VPN (e.g. `foo.otherdomain.invalid`, `bar.baz.otherdomain.invalid` should be redirected through the VPN).  What can I add to this file to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You likely cant. VPNs act on IP addresses, not domain names.

You can likely get an approximation of the desired behaviour by finding the IP addresses used by otherdomain.invalid and its subdomains, and then add appropriate route lines in your config - eg

```
  route 1.2.3.0 255.255.255.0
```

To send everything for 1.2.3.x out via the VPN.

Ive not tried it, but it might be possible to change this to

```
  route otherdomain.invalid 255.255.255.255
  route subdomain.otherdomain.invalid 255.255.255.255
```

to your config file.  Assuming this works it will route traffic to the IP addresses (as resolved when the tunnel is brought up) through the vpn - but not neccissarily associated records like MX records or records related to the subdomain.  It likely wont work fully where the donain resolves to multiple A records (as some clusters do)